# Dataframe not available in the next field in iPython notebook

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I hope someone can help me with this problem. I'm new to iPython Notebook, so apologies... I run my script and in the end store the data into a data frame. But then when I jump to the next line and try to access it for future analysis I get this error: `NameError: name 'parties' is not defined` where parties is the name of my df. All I do is build the df from a list of dictionaries: `parties = pd.DataFrame(alldict)` within my code which I run using `main()`. I can print and access the df within the code with no problems but if I jump to the next line in the notebook I get this error. Should I save it in a different way? I'll appreciate your advice. Below a screenshot where you can see that I can manipulate the df inside the main but not outside.

[image]

Comment: Did you just re-open the notebook after closing it? If so, you'll need to run all cells again. Cell >>> Run All

Comment: No, I didn't. I run the next cell straight after running the script. I also tried to restart all and run all cells.

Comment: Also, why is it indented ? Are you creating the df in a function? That would explain the issue.

Comment: It is indented because I have def Main():    before that running some other functions.

Comment: That's likely the problem here. You need to create the dataframe in a global context.

Comment: so 'if __name__ == '__main__':' is what you put in a .py file to allow for running it from the command line as an executable. I think you want to kill that

Comment: also, if you are creating *parties* within a function, you need to return it from that function to have access to it, as @AndrewL was saying as well. try killing the if _name ==.. part and say instead (indented to line up with the print statements) return parties

Comment: I tried that but got the same result. I opted to save my output to a csv file and then read it again.